# TFS API - Why is the AllowedFieldValues for 'Reasons' empty?

Tags: api

I'm trying to retrieve the list of valid Reasons for a WorkItem (MS Agile 5 template), which works correctly for a new work item.

However for editing existing work items, the AllowedValues is always empty, whatever the state.

```
WorkItem item = GetItem(...)
item.Fields["Reason"].AllowedValues.ToList() // always empty
```

*(`ToList` is my own extension method).*

The problem is, the Visual Studio UI correctly updates the Reasons list when you change the state in the drop down list.

The Reason field also has `IsLimitedToAllowedValues=false` but when you enter an arbitary value it complains that it's not a valid list item.

Answer (score 1):

We also use MS Agile 5 & the following worked fine on an existing work items named `myWorkItem` (I tried with User Story & Task):

```
 FieldDefinitionCollection fdc = myWorkItem.Type.FieldDefinitions;
 Console.WriteLine(myWorkItem.Type.Name);
 foreach (FieldDefinition fd in fdc)
 {
    if(fd.Name == "Reason")
    {
      AllowedValuesCollection avc = fd.AllowedValues;
      foreach (string allowedValue in avc)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(allowedValue.ToString());
      }
    }                     
 }
```

Comment: This is **all** allowed values for the field though, not for a particular state (e.g. Resolved). I think this is a bug as `IsLimitedToAllowedValues` and `HasAllowedValuesList` are both false but save fails if you set the reason to "blah"